# Where Can I connect my C-wire on A Hot Water (Hydronic) Heating System?

Tags: heating, thermostat-c-wire, nest, hydronic

I have a hydronic heating system (Lochnivar)that came controlled with an older (dumb)[image] thermostat. I have 5 wires behind the wall and 5 wire in the wire packet going into heating system however only the red and white wires are connected on both sides. The remaining wires (Yellow, Green, Blue) are not connected on either end.

I'm installing a smart thermostat that needs a C-wire, where can I connect that on the circuit board of my system (picture attached)? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Is there an air handler (fan coil) in your system, or do you have radiators/baseboards/underfloor heat only?

Comment: No air handler, no AC, the underfloor heating (hydronic) is all that's here.

Comment: What model is your boiler then?

Comment: It appears most similar to this one but I’m not able to locate a model # anywhere

https://www.lochinvar.com/products/residential-boilers/noble-boiler

Comment: Hm.  Looking at the install manual for the Noble doesn't give any clues either...

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and most importantly [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers). Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in there.  that's a DC circuit and a "C" wire is an AC thing.

you'll need to use an auxillary power supply to run your smart thermostat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've located a simple auxiliary power supply that plugs into the wall, will post when I confirm the solution